# How to pass arguments to callback in React + Typescript without new function creation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Say you have the following TSX code:

```
render() {
    const someParameter = 5;

    return (
        <div onClick={() => this.doSomething(someParameter)}></div>
    );
}
```

Now, we know that *we shouldn't pass fat arrow functions* like this to the onClick handler because it will create a new function every time, forcing a rerender (this is especially bad when we're passing this callback to a deep component, not just a div).

So then the solution, if there were no parameters, would be to bind `doSomething` to `this` in the constructor of our class, like `this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this)` and then pass the bound function as the callback. However, this doesn't cut it in our case, because we want to pass a parameter to the function - someParameter. Imagine that someParameter wasn't just a stupid constant like it is above, but instead an element in an array that we get in a map() over an array in our render method. How do we handle this situation? That is, how do we pass a function that is not created from scratch every time, thereby breaking our ability to smartly rerender only when necessary?

Thanks!

Comment: We really should benchmark our applications before determining `"that we shouldn't pass fat arrow functions"` in such contexts. Sure, it is suboptimal if render is called _many_ times, but otherwise it is likely fine. It also reads very clearly and will be type-checked.

Comment: I agree with Aluan. If you're not having performance problems, you may not need to worry about this. Unless you're causing a massive cascade of re-rendering, you're probably fine in terms of computational cost, and you can worry about clarity and brevity instead.

Comment: It destroys a big part of the benefit of using Redux, though, especially if you're passing the callback at a high level. Also, my question wasn't "discuss the benefits of this performance optimization" - it was "how do we do this?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bind` allows to bind not only context but also parameters. So you can do something like this in constructor:

```
this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this, someArgument)
```

Above solution will work only if `someArgument` doesn't change during component lifecycle.
If this argument is going to be dynamic the only solution is to use arrow function like in your example - but please note that might casue additional re-rendering only if this function is passed as a prop to child components (not HTML elements). According to react docs:

> In most cases, this is fine. However, if this callback is passed as a
>   prop to lower components, those components might do an extra
>   re-rendering.

If you don't pass it to React child component it shouldn't be a problem and will not cause any additional re-rendering.  Please note that there is a difference between React components and HTML tags. If you use arrow function as event callback on HTML element (e.g. on div generated in map) it will not trigger additional rendering of this `div` because it's not a component and doesn't have render method. React Virtual DOM algorithm will decide if actuall DOM element corresponding to this `div` should be updated and in our case existing DOM element will not be updated (you can check it using dev tools).

```js
class Hello extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {test: 0};
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    var i =0;
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      i++;
     this.setState({test: i})
    }, 1000)
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer)
  }
  render() {
    return (<div>{this.state.test}
      {
        [1, 4, 6].map((v) => {
          return (<div key={v} onClick={() => { console.log(this.state.test)}}>test</div>)
        })
      }
    </div>);
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

You can inspect outoput generated by above code snippet to see that `div` elements are not updated in DOM although they have arrow function defined as event callback and parent component it being re-rendred.

In case you need to pass this function to child component you can separetely pass prop with function and prop with argument value to avoid extre re-rendering (of course you also have to implement `shouldComponentUpdate`):

```
<SomeComponent myClick={this.doSomething} myArgument={someArgument} />
```

and somewhere in SomeComponent:

```
//JSX in SomeComponent render method
<div onClick={() => this.props.myClick(this.props.myArgument)} >...</div>
```

You can also create additional method in SomeComponent instead of using an arrow function:

```
handleMyClick() {
   this.props.myClick(this.props.myArgument);
}
```

and then use it JSX:

```
<div onClick={this.handleMyClick} >...</div>
```

So to sum up: if you use arrow function as event callback on HTML tags it shouldn't cause performance problems and it will not trigger any additional re-rendering - it will not break ability to smartly rerender only when necessary. It may cause additional re-rendering only if arrow function is passed down as prop to child components and in such case you can use soulution suggested by me.

Comment: Bind also creates a new function. Additionally, the function it creates likely has more overhead than an `=>` function since it has a prototype and whatnot.

Comment: Yes, but bind is called only once in constructor not on every re-render. As I mentioned `bind` should be used in constructor

Comment: Ah, I see, excellent point. In that case, I would still prefer `this.doSomething = something => {...};` for readability but I suppose that is suggestive. Bind may be more readable depending on your background

Comment: This would work, as noted by Aleks in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45197271/4089318 , but unfortunately this is very heavy - every time I want to pass a callback with parameters I'll need to wrap it in its own component.

Comment: @MichaelTontchev not if you use `=>` to define a bound function as suggested above.

Comment: @MichaelTontchev I think you've misunderstood me. You don't need to wrap it in its own component. It's just an example to show how you can pass callback to already existing child component to avoid triggerring additional re-renders of this child component. If you want to add event callback to HTML element (not React component) you can use `bind` or arrow function and it shouldn't cause any problems and you don't have to wrap it in component. Using arrow function as prop on HTML element doesn't cause any additional re-renders - it may be problem only if you pass it to child React component

Comment: @BartekFryzowicz - what if in the current component you have to render a bunch of divs with map(), each of which has to have its own callback parameterized by a specific value from the map()? That's the hard case.

Comment: @AluanHaddad - I'm not sure your solution solves the problem with all the parameters - no additional function creation but also allowing to pass parameters to children - can you give a code snippet to show what you mean?

Comment: I'm just suggesting that you define the callback as a bound member function by writing `export default class { constructor() { this.m = args => {...}; } }` this will create the function only once per instantiation of the class, the function will capture `this` properly, and whatever arguments it takes will not change depending on context.

Comment: @Michael Tontchev If you want to pass a event callback to `div` (so to HTML element not to React component) inside a `map` you can use arrow function because as I mentioned it will not cause additional re-rendering of those divs. Only React components (`div` is not React component) may be re-rendered when new function is passed as prop.  Futhermore, creating new arrow function on each parent component render shouldn't cause any performance problems. So to sum up: you can pass arrow function to divs generated in map and you should avoid it if you pass it to React component.

Comment: @BartekFryzowicz - I don't mean to sound rude, but what is the source for the claim why the HTML-only JSX elements would not update? It doesn't make sense that they wouldn't update - they would notice a new function being passed to them, and hence the DOM would need to be updated (that is, a new function bound to them). The following article gives an example of a simple JSX button being updated when its onClick callback is created with a bind(): https://daveceddia.com/avoid-bind-when-passing-props/

Comment: @MichaelTontchev have you checked my code snippet using dev-tools? Dev-tools highlights every DOM element that has been updated but as you can see 'div' elements in the code snippet are not being updated although they receive new function as event callback every second. This is thanks to Virtual DOM optimizations - DOM elements are updated only when there's 'visible' change. Changing event callback doesn't require DOM tree to be updated because it doesn't make visual changes in DOM. Of course new event handler is added in 'background' but it can be done without re-rendering actual DOM elements

Comment: As for the provided article there is no word about DOM updates :) I understand your concerns but I just want to assure you that using 'bind' or arrow functions as event callbacks in React is not that bad especially when using it on HTML elements (please remember that there is a diference between React components and HTML elements)

Comment: Huh! I had not seen the code snippet - I guess it was added after I initially read your response. Alright, yeah, I checked dev tools and I'm convinced there's no DOM manipulation happening. What you said makes sense - the DOM doesn't need to change, just the handlers. Thanks so much for your very thorough response and persistence! I wish I could give you more upvotes :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check solution proposed here in "Protips" section?
https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md

Looks as if this might work:

```
    var List = createReactClass({
              render() {
        return (
          <ul>
            {this.props.items.map(item =>
              <ListItem key={item.id} item={item} onItemClick={this.props.onItemClick} />
            )}
          </ul>
        );
      }
    });

    var ListItem = createReactClass({
      render() {
        return (
          <li onClick={this._onClick}>
            ...
          </li>
        );
      },
      _onClick() {
        this.props.onItemClick(this.props.item.id);
      }
    });
```